# For-Each tag not printing based on Two separate Detail Section Tag in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am facing issue while printing 2nd loop for each Detail Tag. Below is the xml and xslt 1.0 code below and expected output

```
-- XML for the xslt
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="Test">
      <Detail>
      <Supplier>Supplier_1</Supplier>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Ashwin</PersonName>
          <State>KS</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Lingam</PersonName>
          <State>AZ</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1001</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>John</PersonName>
          <State>KS</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
         <Member>
          <CompanyName>Flipkart</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Larry</PersonName>
          <State>IL</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <CombinedState>No</CombinedState>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Flipkart</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Lingam</PersonName>
          <State>NJ</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1001</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Addidas</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>John</PersonName>
          <State>FL</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
      </Detail>
       <Detail>
       <Supplier>Supplier_2</Supplier>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Akhil</PersonName>
          <State>KS</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Sebastian</PersonName>
          <State>AZ</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1001</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
         <Member>
          <CompanyName>Flipkart</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Larry</PersonName>
          <State>IL</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1000</Amount>
          <CombinedState>No</CombinedState>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <CompanyName>Flipkart</CompanyName>
          <PersonName>Lingam</PersonName>
          <State>NJ</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Amount>1001</Amount>
          <CombinedState>Yes</CombinedState>
        </Member>
      </Detail>
    </ns0:Root>
```

Below is the XSLT code 1.0 that I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" xmlns:s0="Test" xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Output" 
xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
  <xsl:key name="group1" match="Member" use="CompanyName"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
    <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="'&quot;1&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="'&quot;1234567&quot;'"/>
    <ns0:Root>
      <T>
        <SeqNo>
          <xsl:value-of select="$var:v1"/>
        </SeqNo>
        <Name>
          <xsl:value-of select="$var:v2"/>
        </Name>
      </T>
                <xsl:for-each select="Detail">
                
      <xsl:for-each select="Member[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('group1',CompanyName))]">
                 <xsl:if test="(CompanyName='Oracle')">
        <Group>
          <A>
            <CompanyName>
              <xsl:value-of select="CompanyName/text()"/>
            </CompanyName>
            <Segment>
              <xsl:value-of select="'A'"/>
            </Segment>
          </A>
        </Group>
                                           </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:Root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Output">
   <T>
      <SeqNo>"1"</SeqNo>
      <Name>"1234567"</Name>
   </T>
   <Group>
      <A>
         <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
         <Segment>A</Segment>
      </A>
   </Group>
      <Group>
      <A>
         <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
         <Segment>A</Segment>
      </A>
   </Group>
</ns0:Root>
```

But I am now only getting one Oracle, whereas i require two Oracle section from its each Detail Tag for loop.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group `Members` by `CompanyName` separately for each `Detail`, then you must include the `Detail`'s id in the key used for grouping, for example:

```
<xsl:key name="group1" match="Member" use="concatCompanyName, '|', generate-id(..)"/>
```

However, since it seems you are only interested in one specific `CompanyName`, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="Test">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <T>
            <!-- omitted -->
        </T>
        <xsl:for-each select="Detail">
            <Group>
                <xsl:if test="Member/CompanyName='Oracle'">
                    <A>
                        <CompanyName>Oracle</CompanyName>
                        <Segment>A</Segment>
                    </A>
                </xsl:if>
            </Group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k , The below code is much more useful for my requirement. ```<xsl:key name="group1" match="Member" use="concatCompanyName, '|', generate-id(..)"/>``` ......As the requirement is to group by CompanyName for each Detail tag and as the company Name is dynamic, Could you please let me know how can I group by different supplier in the Detail tag. Also could you please let me know what should be given inside the generate-id(..) .

Comment: *"what should be given inside the generate-id(..)"* Exactly what is inside now: a reference to the parent element.